# Unable to alter a view: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle

I want to change `FND_LOOKUPS` by adding a new column and the SQL statement is :

```
alter table FND_LOOKUPS add Tag VARCHAR2(150 CHAR);
```

But the error :

> " ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

always shows.

While `FND_LOOKUPS` does exist.

I checked the duplicate issues and grant the access by:

```
GRANT ALL  ON FND_LOOKUPS TO public;
```

And it prompts grant successfully, but the issue still exists.

What's the possible reason for this issue?

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the table exist in the schema you are trying to access?

Comment: @Sid Yes, I use SELECT *
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW')
AND object_name = 'FND_LOOKUPS'; to check it, if you mean this...

Comment: can you try the query with an explicit schema name prepended?

Comment: So what OBJECT_TYPE is `fnd_lookups`? Your query on `all_objects` would return a result if it were a view. Also, what is the owner of the table? Do you get a hit if you query on `user_tables` instead?

Comment: @APC The object type is View. So the problem converts to how to add a column to a view?

Comment: @APC Thanks so much for your reminding. The root cause is that 'fnd_lookups' is not a table but a view. Now I have successfully added the column to the view.

Comment: @drhagen and everybody else - the answer posted by Elva does actually answer their question so it should not have been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for misleading you guys. I use the following statement to check the "table" and found the object type is a VIEW:

```
SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW') AND object_name = 'FND_LOOKUPS'
```

So the issue should be **how to alter a view** by adding one column to it.

I use the following syntax to achieve this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE <optional: FORCE EDITIONABLE> VIEW "user_name"."view_name" (all coloumns) AS
  <select statement>
FROM
  <basic table>
WHERE
  <whereclause>
```

It works fine at last.

Thanks very much to you.